# Yum Update Wiped /boot/efi/EFI directory!

Tags: centos, yum

During a recent yum update (not upgrade), the /boot/efi/EFI/centos and BOOT was removed. Yes, I can reproduce this error.

In order to fix -- I could not boot into the kernel ==>

I used the rescue usb to yum re-install the kernels. And then restored BOOT and centos via a backup.

Then did:

```
grub2-mkconfig to update grub.cfg
```

— placed it in both /boot/grub2 and /boot/efi/EFI/centos. (The boot menu is read from grub2.cfg in the EFI since my machine is EFI.)

What is with yum these days -- very unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in modern RHEL/CentOS the `/boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` should have just a few lines to tell GRUB the filesystem UUID and pathname for the real config file at `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. The exact lines will depend on whether you have a separate `/boot` partition or not, and whether you're using any of LVM / softRAID / disk encryption (separately or in any combination) or none of them.

If you placed the same configuration file to both locations, it will certainly work now, but you may find that your boot menu won't update when a new kernel update is released, as the automatic update process will only update the version in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Have you already submitted a bug report on `yum`? If not, you probably should.